# BINARY to DECIMAL in Lisp - using a non-nested list

Tags: list, binary, lisp, decimal

My goal is to take the same functionality represented in [this S.O. post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22668217/decimal-to-binary-in-lisp-make-a-non-nested-list) and reverse it.

The original poster's goal was to **convert decimal to binary in Lisp (and) make a non-nested list**.  In other words, the 1's and 0's of the output will be in a single list.

I am trying to do the exact opposite- take a non-nested list representing a binary number, and convert it to a decimal.

Has anyone done this before?  Have any pointers?

Comment: 'Don't ask about... Questions you haven't *tried* to find an answer for (show your work!)'

Comment: Use repeated addition and multiplication, like you would if you had a list containing the decimal representation, but using 2 instead of 10.

Comment: If you want to convert a list of binary digits to decimal, you need to have an accumulator, initialised to 0, then for every digit in your list you need to double your accumulator and then add the next digit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just off the cuff of my sleeve:

```
$ clisp -q
[1]> (reduce (lambda (x y) (+ (* 2 x) y)) '(1 0 0 1))
9
[2]> (reduce (lambda (x y) (+ (* 2 x) y)) '(1 0 1 1))
11
```

Just joking; I'm wearing a T-shirt.

Comment: That's brilliant.  How could I make that expression the body of the function, and use an input-list-variable in place of a literal list e.g. ('1011)?  So far I've tried this:      (defvar aList (list 1 0 0 1 1))

(defun bin-to-dec (L)
  (reduce (lambda (x y) (+ (* 2 x) y)) (L))
)

(bin-to-dec aList)       but I get a error "Symbol's function definition is void"

Comment: For that, you just have to learn to program in Lisp. There are great tutorials out there.  Touretzky's *Gentle Introduction to Lisp* book, or whateer it is called. Shapiro's *Common Lisp: an Interactive Approach* (now out of print, but a free PDF download). And others.